# Why am I getting this NameError: name "dt' is not defined

Tags: python, datetime, nameerror

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to scrape reddit and convert the UNIX timestamp into a date. However, when I run this code I'm getting a Name Error. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? Thanks.

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_date(created):
    return dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(created)

_timestamp = topics_data["created"].apply(get_date)
```

Comment: The error message is quite clearn, the name `dt` is not defined anywhere. Why did you *expect* it to be defined?

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: I'm sure the error was quite clear.  They weren't asking the meaning.  They were asking why isn't their environment state as they expected.  When I was first learning python, I expected basic functionality like date handling to be already loaded when the environment is initiated.  But when somebody asks "why am I getting this error", they are often not needing the error to be explained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dt` means nothing in your current code what the interpreter kindly tells you.

What you're trying to do is to call a `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`

You can change your `import` to:

```py
import datetime as dt
```

and then `dt` will be an alias for `datetime` package so `dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(created)` will work.

But this is not the only solution. The below also will work:

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created)
```

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(created)
```

You can check [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) out to have a better understatement of the differences.